# Export variant data type with other datatype columns

Tags: google-bigquery, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I like to export to GCS bucket which is having variant data type and normal data type and after loaded data into GCS bucket then load into Snowflake using COPY command.

I tried with UNNEST command but it work with only one column but I Have to export with all table column and then load into SNOWFLAKE

Comment: Please clarify the issue you are having, is it with the export or the import? Please provide some sample data and what you are trying to achieve with it

Comment: As there is normal data and variant data into table. So that I export in JSON format. When I tried to import that file into Snowflake using COPY command then it saying that for variant data type column we can use only one column  but I have to import string data type column with variant data type also. So please help me on this or let me know if you required more information on this.

Comment: Please paste the full COPY command that you are using into your question and also the FILE FORMAT (if it is a custom file format that you've created). Also, what is the structure of the file you are copying from - how many columns does it have and what  do the columns contain?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you refer to tabular data as normal and object and arrays as variants. I'd export the data from BigQuery using `EXPORT DATA` in JSON format like so:

```sql
EXPORT DATA
OPTIONS ( 
    uri = 'gs://{bucket_name}/*.json.gz',
    format='JSON',
    compression='GZIP',
    overwrite=FALSE 
    ) AS
SELECT * FROM `{project}.{dataset}.{table}`
```

Then in Snowflake do:

```sql
-- run this if you don't have a storage integration yet
create storage integration if not exists {storage_integration}
  type = external_stage
  storage_provider = gcs
  enabled = true
  storage_allowed_locations = ('gcs://{bucket_name}/');


-- get the STORAGE_GCP_SERVICE_ACCOUNT and assign permissions in Google Cloud IAM to list, read and write (optional) in the {bucket_name}
desc storage integration {storage_integration};


-- you will need this file format to read the file in GCS correctly
create file format if not exists {file_format}
  type = 'json'
  compression = 'gzip'
  strip_outer_array = true;


-- link the bucket to Snowflake using Stages
create stage if not exists {stage}
  url='gcs://{bucket_name}/'
  storage_integration = {storage_integration};


-- finally you need a table with a variant column. I usually have a table called RAW with this definition
create table if not exists {table} (
    filename varchar(1024),
    file_row_number int,
    json_data variant
);


-- then I copy the data using the COPY INTO statement
copy into {table} from
(select 
    metadata$filename,
    metadata$file_row_number,
    t.$1 
from 
    @{stage} 
    (file_format => {file_format}) t
)
```

After loading the data in variant format can you start doing more complex queries using the `col:param` or `col['param']` notation.

Example:

```sql
select
  json_data['user_id']::string user_id,
  json_data['timestamp']::timestamp timestamp
from
  {table}
```